# Jasmine-Karma UnitTest running single vs running all

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

When I run whole unit tests in a package, some of tests get fail although running individually those tests get success.  I dont know what is affecting running in a set.

After executing "ng test --code-coverage" command, Jasmine-Karma creates the following output.

**Component1**
 - Test Case 1 = Pass
 - Test Case 2 = Pass
 - Test Case 3 = Pass

**Component2**
 - Test Case 1 = Pass / 
 - Test Case 2 = Fail /
 - Test Case 3 = Pass /

For instance, if I run only Com2-Case2, it gets pass.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the typical unit test sample:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer.component';

describe('FooterComponent', () => {

    let comp: FooterComponent;
    let fixt: ComponentFixture<FooterComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({

            declarations: [FooterComponent],

            imports: [
                TranslateModule.forRoot(),
            ],

        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixt = TestBed.createComponent(FooterComponent);
        comp = fixt.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should create component === FooterComponent', () => {
        expect(comp).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

Comment: This could be an issue because of not resetting the test data properly after each test case.

Comment: Can you show an example of the test in question (Com2-Case2) as well as any setup or test bootstrapping code?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by using "FakeSync" and "Tick".

I realized that if there is subscription inside of test case call, it is affecting the  next test case. To overcome the issue, Tick was the solution.

```
it('should create TranslationTexts', fakeAsync(() => {
    comp.ngOnInit();
    tick();
    expect(JSON.stringify(comp.translationTexts).length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
}));
```

Tick helps to wait until async call is done.
The following resource was very helpful.

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was a caching issue. Restarting Karma fixed the problem.
For some reason, the "TestAll" tests were cached and fixing them separately did not change the result of the "TestAll" tests (while they did individually)